# Независимость процессов

Tags: java

Есть форма такая:

[image: форма]

По нажатиям на клавиши происходят некоторые действия. Меня интересует вот что. Я хочу чтобы вместе с этим, независимо от кнопок исполнялся код. Ну пускай код будет такой: в новый тектфилд будет ежесекундно выводиться время. Как это сделать? просто в маин вписать код который нужен?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я лично ничего не понял. Что надо сделать то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;

    public class mainPanel extends JFrame
    {
        JButton button;
        JTextField textField;
        public mainPanel()
        {
            button = new JButton("Click me!");
            textField = new JTextField();

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    textField.setBackground(getRandomColor());
                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));  
            add(textField);
            add(button);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(256, 256, 320, 180);
            setSize(320, 180);
            setVisible(true);

            new Worker(textField).execute();
        }

        private Color getRandomColor() //bright color gen
        {
            int red =   (int)((Math.random() * 106)) + 150;
            int green = (int)((Math.random() * 106)) + 150;
            int blue =  (int)((Math.random() * 106)) + 150;
            return new Color(red, green, blue);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            new mainPanel();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    class Worker extends SwingWorker<String, String>
    {
        JTextField textField;

        Worker(JTextField textField)
        {
            this.textField = textField;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            while(true)
            {
                textField.setText(getCurrentTime());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        String getCurrentTime()
        {
            int Hour = LocalDateTime.now().getHour();
            int Minute = LocalDateTime.now().getMinute();
            int Second = LocalDateTime.now().getSecond();
            return "" + 
                    (Hour < 10 ? "0" + Hour : Hour) + ":" +
                    (Minute < 10 ? "0" + Minute : Minute) + ":" +
                    (Second < 10 ? "0" + Second : Second);
         }
    }
```

Сразу хочу предупредить, что я студент первого курса, следовательно, опыта в программировании нет. Мне очень интересно знать, какие замечания сделают опытные программисты. Я надеюсь, что код понятен и без комментариев.

Советую прочитать книгу Иван Портянкин, Swing: Эффектные пользовательские интерфейсы

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но вы меня не поняли. Я про время для примера написал. Я спрашиваю как реализовать, а не готовый код интересует.

Comment: @Korts да, точно, прошу прощения. Давайте разбираться. В принципе, если писать код в main, то он будет в отдельном потоке. То есть, даже при том, что main зависнет, UI будет отвечать на запросы, благодаря тому, что он исполняется в отдельном потоке Event Dispatch Thread. Так вот, этот самый EDT отвечает за приём и доставку событий, следовательно, в нем нельзя проделывать никакую другую работу. Но и с другой стороны, нельзя работать с компонентами UI из других потоков, а не из EDT напрямую, так как это рано или поздно приведёт к непредсказуемым последствиям. Поэтому, я показал..................

Comment: @Korts пример использования SwingWorker, который позволяет удобно сообщать компонентам UI обо всех изменениях в отдельных потоках. Кстати, советую запускать приложения используя SwingUtilites.  Если уж совсем не получается, то можете как нибудь исходники скинуть, я попробую сам сделать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь. Буду изучать.